# Install a package parallel to /opt/ros

Tags: ros-melodic, catkin, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a custom package that I built. I ran bloom-generate rosdebian on the package and generated a debian folder. When I looked into debian/rules, I saw the following,

```
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="/opt/ros/melodic" \
-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/opt/ros/melodic"
```

I want to install my package to a location something like `/opt/custom/melodic`. These are the steps I'm following right now. Currently, I clone the package, run the following commands to generate a binary. I'm resolving the dependencies with a python script I custom brewed.

```
bloom-generate rosdebian
dpkg-buildpackage -b -us -uc
```

When the binary is installed, it gets installed into `/opt/ros/melodic`. Help much appreciated. Thanks !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/316779/install-a-package-parallel-to-/opt/ros/) by [venkisagunner](https://answers.ros.org/users/29258/venkisagunner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 89 on 2019-02-26

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like it's not possible to modify the installation prefix with the `rosdebian` generator (but you can try method below just to make sure):
https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/bloom/blob/master/bloom/generators/rosdebian.py#L53

But with the `debian` generator you can choose what is going to be the installation prefix with the `--install-prefix`:
[bloom/generators/debian/generator.py](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/bloom/blob/9e81373b0e9be8d0e154dcc57ec8530b4ddc8ea5/bloom/generators/debian/generator.py#L594) (update 20200603 by @130s permalink)

However the help command does not seem to be up to date:

```
$ bloom-generate debian --help
usage: bloom-generate debian [-h]
                             [--place-template-files | --process-template-files]
                             [--os-name OS_NAME] [--os-version OS_VERSION]
                             [--ros-distro ROS_DISTRO] [--native] [-d]
                             [--version] [--unsafe]
                             [package_path]

Generates debian packaging files for a catkin package

positional arguments:
  package_path          path to or containing the package.xml of a package

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --place-template-files
                        places debian/* template files only
  --process-template-files
                        processes templates in debian/* only
  --os-name OS_NAME     OS name, e.g. ubuntu, debian
  --os-version OS_VERSION
                        OS version or codename, e.g. precise, wheezy
  --ros-distro ROS_DISTRO
                        ROS distro, e.g. indigo, kinetic, lunar, melodic (used
                        for rosdep)
  --native              generate native package

global:
  -d, --debug           enable debug messages
  --version             prints the bloom version
  --unsafe              Makes bloom faster, but if there is an error then you
                        could run into trouble.
```

---

Originally posted by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) with karma: 1505 on 2019-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2019-02-27**:
I've opened an issue because I think the documentation is incomplete: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/bloom/issues/518

**Comment by [venkisagunner](https://answers.ros.org/users/29258/venkisagunner/) on 2019-02-27**:
It didnt work. I guess, there is capability to change the prefix path as you mentioned but the front end doesnt support that.

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2019-02-28**:
As a last resort you can still tweak the `debian/rules` using `sed`.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2020-06-03**:
Nice info! I just found a follow-up https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/bloom/issues/518#issuecomment-481872095 clarifying that in order to utilize `--install-prefix` `git-bloom-generate` should be used (which has different args and contexts so exact same args and flow doesn't work though).